# How can I automatically install all missing dependencies from pip check?

Tags: python, pip

When I run `pip check` I get a list of missing dependencies of installed packages, e.g.:

```
beautysh 6.2.1 requires colorama, which is not installed.
```

How can I automatically install all missing dependencies? Is there a way for `pip` to handle this? Or should I start messing with piping `pip check` to `sed` and `xargs`?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```sh
pip check | sed -rn 's/.*requires ([^,]+),.*/\1/p' | xargs pip install
```

But I'm still hoping for a flag to `pip check` or `pip install`, something like that